UTF-16 as sequence of code units in python
I have the string 'abç' which in UTF-8 is b'ab\xc3\xa7'.
I want it in UTF-16, but not this way:
b'ab\xc3\xa7'.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-16-be')

which gives me:
b'\x00a\x00b\x00\xe7'
The answer I want is the UTF-16 code units, that is, a list of int:

[32, 33, 327]

Is there any straightforward way to do that?
And of course, the reverse. Given a list of ints which are UTF-16 code units, how do I convert that to UTF-8?

327 is 'Ň' not 'ç', which is 231, which you can tell from the output (xe7 is 231 decimal). Also, 'a' and 'b' are 97 and 98, not 32 and 33, which would be a space and an exclamation mark.

BTW: 'abç'.encode('utf-16-be') is much easier and simpler than b'ab\xc3\xa7'.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-16-be'). It still isn't clear what you really want. Codepoints? 16-bit integers? Depending on why you want it, that may also affect the best way to do it, so it would help if you provided that info in your question, at least as context.

Technically they are not code units.

The simple solution that may work in many cases would be something like:
def sort_of_get_utf16_code_units(s):
    return list(map(ord, s))


print(sort_of_get_utf16_code_units('abç')

Output:
[97, 98, 231]

However, that doesn't work for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP):
print(sort_of_get_utf16_code_units(''))

Output is the Unicode code point:
[128522]

Where you might have expected the code units (as your question states):
[55357, 56842]

To get that:
def get_utf16_code_units(s):
    utf16_bytes = s.encode('utf-16-be')
    return [int.from_bytes(utf16_bytes[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(utf16_bytes), 2)]


print(get_utf16_code_units(''))

Output:
[55357, 56842]

Doing the reverse is similar:
def utf16_code_units_to_string(code_units):
    utf16_bytes = b''.join([unit.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big') for unit in code_units])
    return utf16_bytes.decode('utf-16-be')


print(utf16_code_units_to_string([55357, 56842]))

Output:


The byteorder is 'big' by default, but it doesn't hurt to be specific there.

You could also use a lambda function: get_utf16_code_units = lambda b: [int.from_bytes(b .encode('utf-16-be')[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(b .encode('utf-16-be')), 2)], and utf16_code_units_to_string = lambda c: (b''.join([unit.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big') for unit in c])).decode('utf-16-be')

It's bad practice to assign a lambda to a name, there's no benefit other than saving a line in a text file, and there's clear downsides to both performance and readability.

@Grismar How does it affect performance?

Yeah, it compiles to exactly the same bytecode.

Use array.array to quickly unpack a byte string as unsigned shorts to get UTF-16 code units:
import array

def utf16_code_units(s):
    return array.array('H', s.encode('utf-16le')).tolist()

print(utf16_code_units('abç'))

Output:
[97, 98, 231, 55357, 56489]

If looking for performance, .tolist() is optional as array.array is list-like:
>>> array.array('H', 'abç'.encode('utf-16le'))
array('H', [97, 98, 231, 55357, 56489])


If I understand the question correctly you want the decimal values of the codepoints for each character as it would be represented in UTF-16, so for characters outside the BMP, you'd use surrogate pairs.
I'll use a generic function that can handle UTF-8 (and by extension UTF-32) and UTF-16 and handle both hexadecimal and decimal representations.
The first takes a string and creates a list of codepoints in either hexadecimal (default) or decimal:
def chars_to_codepoints(chars, decimal=False, enc='utf-8'):
    enc = enc.lower()
    result = []
    for char in chars:
        if ord(char) > 0xffff and enc == 'utf-16':
            b = bytes(char, 'utf-16-be')
            s1 = "".join(["{:02x}".format(x) for x in b[0:2]]).upper()
            s2 = "".join(["{:02x}".format(x) for x in b[2:4]]).upper()
            result.extend([s1, s2])
        else:
            result.append(f'{ord(char):04X}')
    if decimal:
        return [int(r, 16) for r in result]
    return result

s = 'abç '
chars_to_codepoints(s)
# ['0061', '0062', '00E7', '0020', '1F60A']
chars_to_codepoints(s, True)
# [97, 98, 231, 32, 128522]
chars_to_codepoints(s, enc='utf-16')
# ['0061', '0062', '00E7', '0020', 'D83D', 'DE0A']
chars_to_codepoints(s, True, enc='utf-16')
# [97, 98, 231, 32, 55357, 56842]

To go from a sequence of codepoints to a string of characters:
def homogeneous_type(seq, typ):
    return all(isinstance(x, typ) for x in seq)
def codepoints_to_chars(codepoints, enc='utf-8'):
    enc = enc.lower()
    chars = [chr(c) for c in codepoints] if homogeneous_type(codepoints, int) else [chr(int(c, 16)) for c in codepoints]
    if enc == 'utf-16':
        return "".join(chars).encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
    return "".join(chars)

codepoints_to_chars(['0061', '0062', '00E7', '0020', '1F60A'])
# 'abç '
codepoints_to_chars([97, 98, 231, 32, 128522])
# 'abç '
codepoints_to_chars(['0061', '0062', '00E7', '0020', 'D83D', 'DE0A'], enc='utf-16')
# 'abç '
codepoints_to_chars([97, 98, 231, 32, 55357, 56842], enc='utf-16')
# 'abç '

